# getting the index of an array, multiple times, then storing them in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, indexof

I want to get the index of an array which I have done with `Array.IndexOf(array, value)`. This works good with one value but I want to get every occurrence of the value and store the index's into another array. For example, the name 'tom' appears 5 times in an array, I want to find the index positions of each one.

Comment: It's a task, not a question. What have you tried? What problems have you faced?

Comment: (You might want to use LINQ with `Where`, btw...)

Comment: @JonSkeet If he wants the indexes, he doesn't (technically he could, as written by Habib, but it's a pretty big detour)

Comment: I don't think it's that much of a detour, to be honest. It says exactly what's needed...

Comment: No, Ben's code (minus `Count()` plus `Length`) is what is needed... Simple, practical, fast and readable by a junior programmer. Using a semi-obscure overload of `.Select()` to create n temporary objects just to have their index is more like using a cannon to kill an ant. LINQ shouldn't be the solution to all the problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this? This uses a list rather than an array, but it follows the same idea.

```
List<int> Indexes = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
{
    if (array[i] == "tom")
    {
        Indexes.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `.Length` instead of `.Count()`

Answer (score 3):

This solution is like the previous one, but will run faster:

```
string value = "tom";
int[] indices = stringArray.Where(s => s != null)
                           .Select((s, i) => s.Equals(value) ? i: -1)
                           .Where(i => i >= 0)
                           .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you can add another parameter to `IndexOf()`, which will let you specify where in the array to start. This should give you more or less what you need:

```
var indices = new List<int>();
int i = Array.IndexOf(array, val);
while(i > -1){
    indices.Add(i);
    i = Array.IndexOf(array, val, i+1);
} 

// ... and if it is important to have the result as an array:
int[] result = indices.ToArray();
```

Practical example:

```
var array = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 3};
int val = 3;

var indices = new List<int>();    
int i = Array.IndexOf(array, val);
while(i > -1){
    indices.Add(i);
    i = Array.IndexOf(array, val, i+1);
}

// ... and if it is important to have the result as an array:
int[] result = indices.ToArray();
```

**Edit:** Just realized a while-loop may well be a lot cleaner than a for-loop for this.

---

***Edit 2:*** Due to popular demand (see comment below), here`s the original beautiful non-basic for-loop, re-introduced just for your reading pleasure:

```
for(int i = Array.IndexOf(array, val); i > -1; i = Array.IndexOf(array, val, i+1)){
    indices.Add(i);        
}
```

Comment: But... but... that non-basic `for` was so marvelous... it was one of the most beautiful `for` I had ever seen in the last six months... I had upvoted you only for it :-)

Comment: @xanatos Thank you, I feel honored. In fact, I was so deeply moved by your comment, that I have decided to reintroduce the original for-loop. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Could create an extension method to do it

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<int> GetIndicesOf<T>(this T[] target, T val, int start = 0)
        {
            EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            for (int i = start; i < target.Length; i++)
            {
                if (comparer.Equals(target[i], val))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the using statement for your namespace with the extension method `using Extensions;` in the file you want to call it in.

Then to call it just do the following to get the indices.

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = array.GetIndicesOf(value);
```

or to get an array just do

```
int[] indicies = array.GetIndicesOf(value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) overload which uses elements index as well, like:

```
var indices = stringArray.Select((s, i) => new {Value = s, Index = i})
    .Where(r => r.Value == "tom")
    .Select(r => r.Index);
```